# How to add openssl lib in android studio with experimental gradle plugin (NDK)?

Tags: android, c, android-studio, android-ndk, gradle-experimental

I'm trying to add openSSL library to my project in `android studio 2.0 preview 7` with `experimental gradle plugin`.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0'
}
```

What I did is that I downloaded the `openSSL library` and put it into `jni` folder. And I have another .c file that uses this library. I have included the files that I need and there are no errors in code. My `.c` file name is `hello-jni.c` and I declared it into my `build.gradle (module: app)` like this:

```
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "hello-jni"
}
```

and also I loaded my library in my MainActivity like this:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
}
```

but when I try to build my project, an error shows up like this:

```
Error:(51) undefined reference to `RSA_generate_key'
Error:error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:linkArm64-v8aDebugHello-    jniSharedLibrary'.
> A build operation failed.
  Linker failed while linking libhello-jni.so.
```

My hello-jni.c source code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "boringssl/crypto/openssl/base.h"
#include "boringssl/crypto/openssl/rsa.h"
#include "boringssl/crypto/openssl/pem.h"

#define KEY_LENGTH  2048
#define PUB_EXP     3
#define PRINT_KEYS
#define WRITE_TO_FILE 0

size_t pri_len;            // Length of private key
size_t pub_len;            // Length of public key
char   *pri_key;           // Private key
char   *pub_key;           // Public key
char   msg[KEY_LENGTH/8];  // Message to encrypt
char   *encrypt = NULL;    // Encrypted message
char   *decrypt = NULL;    // Decrypted message
char   *err;               // Buffer for any error messages

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_ndktest_SignUpActivity_testString(JNIEnv *env, jobject activity) {

// In this line, the error happens!(in build time)
RSA *keypair = RSA_generate_key(KEY_LENGTH, PUB_EXP, NULL, NULL);

//continue to work with key pair ...

return "some jstring";
}
```

Comment: Did you download all OpenSSL library (including the .c files)? Or only the headers (.h) and static or dynamic libraries (.a, .so)?

Comment: Did you succeed yet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the openssl library as a dependency. There's a snippet [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-0.4.x---0.6.0-alpha1) showing how to add a prebuilt library.